# Error con metodos de PDO en PHP

Tags: php, html5, pdo

**Hola, me podrian ayudar con este error, esto solo me sucede al subirlo a un hosting por que en mi localhost todo va perfecto.**

Me dice que no puedo usar el metodo **prepare()** con un non-object que es el **$pdo** que lo  traigo de mi **include 'global/conexion.php'**
Tambien defino unos constantes que las uso en **include 'global/conexion.php'**

Este es el error:
**Fatal error**
: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in
/home2/wsbinsideuser1/public_html/tienda/index.php
on line
26

Esta es mi conexion:

```
$servidor = "mysql:dbname=".BD.";host=".SERVIDOR;

try{
$pdo = new PDO($servidor,USUARIO,PASSWORD,
array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND=>"SET NAMES utf8"));
//echo "<script> alert('Conectado..')</script>";
}catch(PDOException $e){
    //echo "<script> alert('Error..')</script>";
}
```

y este es el problema en el **index.php**

```
<?php 
include 'templates/cabecera.php';
require 'global/config.php';
require 'global/conexion.php';
include 'carrito.php';
?>
```

**esta es la linea del error**

```
$sentencia = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tblproductos"); 

$sentencia->execute();
$listaProductos=$sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Parece que no está conectando a PDO. Activa el `catch` del error aunque sea temporalmente poniendo esto: `}catch(PDOException $e){
    print_r($e);
}` así te dirá lo que ocurre. Cuidado porque a veces PDO revela las credenciales cuando hay errores, no debes dejar ese `print_r` de forma permanente.

Comment: Si tienes razon no me estoy conectando bien a la BD, listo ya corrigo el print_r

Comment: OJO, no es que dejes el `catch` con el `print_r`, es para que te muestre por pantalla el motivo del error. Cuando funcione conviene manejar bien la captura de errores para evitar lo que dije antes, que PDO revele la contraseña escribiéndola en el log de errores o mostrándola por pantalla. Eso sería peligroso, sobre todo en un contexto en línea.

Comment: Ya solucione los problemas, muchas gracias sos un crack, te calificaria pero no tengo reputacion. Saludos.